# Adding to this simple HTTP request Observable method

Tags: angular, database, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have restaurant objects.

I have a method that returns all restaurants in the database:

```
    getRestaurantAll() : Observable<Restaurant[]>
    {
      return this.http.get<Restaurant[]>(`${this.baseUrl}api/Restaurant`)
        .pipe(
          catchError(this.handleError<Restaurant[]>(`getRestaurantAll`,[]))
        );
    }
```

Now, I want to make a similar method. But with a slight modification.

So there are two important array properties of Restaurant that I'm working with:

```
TypesOfFood
(Pizza, Burgers, Tacos, Ramen)

MethodsOfPayment
(Credit, Debit, Cash, Vouchers)
```

I currently already have the user's selections passed as string variables userFoodChoice and userPaymentChoice.

I would want the user to be presented with a list of Restaurants that ONLY accept BOTH of the selections made.

How would I alter a request like the one at the top of my post to return only the Restaurant's that have both of the users choices?

Comment: pipe a `map()` operator

Answer (score 0):

it's better to do this control on the Backend not the Frontend and have the list of restaurants  that suits users preferences directly prepared from the backend. but if you want to do it on the front end. you can use **map** like this:

```
return this.http.get<Restaurant[]>(`${this.baseUrl}api/Restaurant`)
    .pipe(
      map((res: Restaurant[]) => {
         const filteredRestaurants = res.filter(
            (restaurant) => {
              // put your conditions here
            });
         return filteredRestaurants;
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError<Restaurant[]>(`getRestaurantAll`,[]))
    );
```

Comment: Could you help me out a bit more? When I try to research Map I'm getting many different examples that don't seem anything like what I'm trying to do.

Comment: you mean map from rxjs?

Comment: right, that's what we're adding to the pipe isn't it?

Comment: yes it will change each value sent by your observable, here is an example: const source = from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
//add 10 to each value
const example = source.pipe(map(val => val + 10));
//output: 11,12,13,14,15

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map check this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your request but if you want to filter on the basis of a selection of the two arrays that you have presented, once you have recovered the two values to filter on (in the example filteredTypesOfFood and filteredMethodsOfPayment), you can base the filter on those two (at your chosen whether in OR or AND).

```
filteredTypesOfFood = 'Pizza';
filteredMethodsOfPayment = 'Credit';

...
return this.http.get<Restaurant[]>(`${this.baseUrl}api/Restaurant`)
    .pipe(
      map((res: Restaurant[]) => {
         const filteredRestaurants = res.filter(
            (restaurant) => {
              return (restaurant.type === this.filteredTypesOfFood
                     || restaurant.method === this.filteredMethodsOfPayment);
            });
         return filteredRestaurants;
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError<Restaurant[]>(`getRestaurantAll`,[]))
    );
```

Here a working but simplified example, with only the filter function, with a mock array of restaurants:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-restaurant-filtered-array?file=src/app/app.component.ts